# Не могу изменить переменную PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

Поступаю следующим образом:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('C:\\DjangoPJ\\Acosta\\Blog')
```

Во время сеанса переменная меняется.
однако на попытку импорта реагирует так:

```
>>> import Blog

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import Blog

ImportError: No module named Blog
```

И после перезапуска, тоже ничего не видно. OS - Vista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
>>> sys.path.append('C:\\DjangoPJ\\Acosta')
```

Comment: о! Во время сеанса, import Blog проходит без ошибки, модуль импортируется. Но только в течении одного сеанса. В дальнейшем, снова ошибка.

Comment: Ну правильно, после окончания сенаса вам снова нужно делать sys.path.append, т.к. sys.path - это обычный список. Чтобы работало во всех сеансах, вам нужно дописать путь до папки Acosta в переменную окружения pythonpath. Я к сожалению хардкорный юниксоид, поэтому не могу точно сказать, в какой файл вам нужно прописать свои настройки. Попробуйте воспользоваться этой инструкцией http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Comment: Оно не в файл, а в реестр. Там где-то в Control Panel->Система->Переменные среды.